# Maven - Generate jar manifest with two classpath prefix

Tags: java, maven, jar, classpath, manifest

I'm writing the pom file of my project but i'm facing a problem in classpath entries. In my pom i set

```
plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
/plugin>
```

but with this conf in the generated manifest librairies are supposed to be in lib/. In reality all of them are located either in ..../lib/public/ or ..../lib/private/. 
Is it possible to differentiate librairies location in pom file to have different prefix in generated manifest ?

Thanks